# How to prevent WebStorm from removing imports?

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm is removing unused imports by default. How can I turn this off?

e.g. if I comment out an imported element, the import statement is auto-deleted. When I comment that element back in, I need to manually insert the necessary import statement again.

Often auto-insert of import statements does not help since WebStorm does not recognize that the element has to be imported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unused imports are always removed when optimizing imports, so, if you like to keep them, don't run `Code | Optimize imports`, and make sure that *Optimize Imports* is not enabled in *Reformat Code* dialog: `Code | Show Reformat File dialog`, clear the *Optimize Imports* checkbox

[image]

Comment: It is indeed `Reformat Code` the issue here. But I can not find where to disable 'Optimize Imports' within `Reformat Code`. Could you lead me to the right place in the settings, please?